# Can't find BPM Composer endpoint on weblogic 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, weblogic, soa, business-process-management

I have a weblogic server with 3 managed servers and an admin server

I am trying to access the bpm composer (which is shown as deployed and active)

I have looked under the Deployments > Bpm Composer > Testing (Tab) which clearly states it is running at

```
localhost:8103/bpm/composer
```

However when I attempt to access this I am greeted with a 404.

Annoyingly I am able to access the Console & Enterprise manager, I am thinking the composer might have been hidden or obfuscated somehow as this is our production environment.

Has anyone any idea how to access, or unhide the composer?

Many thanks
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you did not find any exception in the current server log. In fact, getting a 404 indicates that the server is up, but that URL can't be resolved by the server. With this I can think of two possibilities:

- Try to access with the URI 'BPM/Composer' instead of 'bpm/composer', It might not seem logical but i seem to remember in the past that the URI was case-sensitive.
- If the above test URL suggests otherwise, it might be that the composer is not targeted to the server you seem to deploy. Please do review the targeting.

If the above suggest otherwise,

login to console page, navigate under **Home > Summary of Deployments >BPMComposer**, and go to the testing tab. Expand the /bpm/composer/ node. Under 'default' row click on the link under Test Point column.

See if the page opens.

Answer (score 0):

WLS and EM consoles are deployed on your admin server. Composer and other applications are deployed on managed servers.

Check if you can access your managed server from localhost (Eg. try to deploy some composite from jdeveloper).